# Google Sheets Conditional Format Cell Borders

Tags: google-sheets

What is the Google App Script needed to accomplish the following?

On my spreadsheet, I have more than 1 row per day, and I am trying to add a line (thicker and darker than the default one around cells) between each DAY, to make it easy to distinguish between days, essentially, adding a top border to (row 2) A2:L2 if $A2 is not equal to $A1.
The built-in Conditional Formatting only works for color, not for borders.

I tried setBorder in the formula in the cell, but it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Exact copy of [Google Sheets Conditional Format Cell Borders](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/189464434).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cannot be done with conditional formatting nor a custom function. Use an Apps Script function that employs `Array.forEach()` and `Range.offset()`, like this:

```
function insertBorderBetweenDays() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const keyColumn = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A2:A');
  const rangeToFormat = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A2:H');
  insertHorizontalSeparatorBorders(keyColumn, rangeToFormat);
}

/**
* Draws a horizontal border line across rangeToFormat on top
* of cells where the value in keyColumn changes.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range} keyColumn A vertical range that holds keys.
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range} rangeToFormat The range to format.
*/
function insertHorizontalSeparatorBorders(keyColumn, rangeToFormat) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 21 November 2022
  //  - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167829/269219
  const keys = keyColumn.getDisplayValues().flat();
  let previous;
  keys.forEach((key, rowIndex) => {
    if (previous && key !== previous) {
      rangeToFormat.offset(rowIndex, 0, 1)
        .setBorder(true, false, false, false, false, false, 'black', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
    }
    previous = key;
  });
}
```

You can assign the `insertBorderBetweenDays()` function to a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

Comment: How do I make that the above code runs every time a cell is edited?

Comment: Use an `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) to run `insertHorizontalSeparatorBorders(e.range, e.range)` when `e.range.columnStart === 1`. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Can you, please, change the above code so that it runs every time a cell is edited, and repost the code? (I understand the onEdit function would need to be added, but I'm not good in JavaScript ;) )

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).